# MSVC: Covariant Return Types And Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, virtual-inheritance, covariant-return-types

I'm unsure whether this is a bug in the visual-c++ compiler or undefined behaviour.

### Setup

```
struct DummyBase { virtual ~DummyBase() = default; };
struct DummyDerived : virtual public DummyBase {};
```

Just a class and a derived class using virtual inheritance

```
DummyDerived derived;
DummyBase* base = &derived;

std::cout << "Derived : " << &derived << std::endl;
std::cout << "Base    : " << base << std::endl;
```

When casting `DummyDerived*` to  `DummyBase*` the pointer is offset. This seems to be caused by virtual inheritance:

```
Derived : 00000000002CF838
Base    : 00000000002CF840
```

Even though the pointer values are different a comparison will return true:

```
std::cout << "IsSame  : " << (base == &derived) << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
IsSame  : 1
```

So far so good.

### Problem

The problem arises in the following setup:

```
 struct IBaseReturner
 {
   virtual DummyBase* Get() = 0;
 };

 struct IDerivedReturner : public virtual IBaseReturner
 {
   virtual DummyDerived* Get() = 0;
 };

 struct BaseReturner : public virtual IBaseReturner
 {
 };

 struct DerivedReturner : public BaseReturner, public virtual IDerivedReturner
 {
   DummyDerived* Ptr;
   virtual DummyDerived* Get() override { return Ptr; }
 };
```

Here we have interfaces and implementations of classes with methods that return either `DummyBase` or `DummyDerived` overwritten via covariant return types. Again with virtual inheritance.

```
// Setup
DerivedReturner returner;
returner.Ptr = &derived;
IBaseReturner* baseReturner = &returner;
```

Now return `DummyDerived*` from `DerivedReturner` and `DummyBase*` from the same returner cast to `IBaseReturner`:

```
DummyDerived* derivedOriginal = returner.Get();
DummyBase* baseFromInterface = baseReturner->Get();
```

Compare Just like obove:

```
std::cout << "Derived Original    : " << derivedOriginal << std::endl;
std::cout << "Base from Interface : " << baseFromInterface << std::endl;
```

Output

```
Derived Original    : 00000000002CF838
Base from Interface : 00000000002CF838
```

Unlike above the pointers have the SAME value.
Now compare them:

```
std::cout << "IsSame  : " << (baseFromInterface == derivedOriginal) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
IsSame  : 0
```

The comparison returns `false` even tough the adresses are the same. This is expected since the pointer to `DummyBase` should have a different value.
Also when trying to dynamic_cast:

```
std::cout << dynamic_cast<DummyDerived*>(baseFromInterface);
```

And expception is thrown:

```
unknown file: error: C++ exception with description "Access violation - no RTTI data!" thrown in the test body.
```

Obviously since the pointer was not correctly offset.

### Conclusion

It seems as though when calling `IBaseReturner::Get` the visual-c++ compiler fails to do the necessary pointer arithmetic to cast `DummyDerived*` to `DummyBase*`. This happens in vs2013 and vs2015 (didn't try any other version). Also when compiled with gcc it works fine.

### Question

While the setup might be a bit complex the question it rather simple:

Is this a msvc bug or am I causing undefined behavoiur?

Added an online example : http://rextester.com/KHZXGQ27304

Comment: I am modestly surprised `IBaseReturner* baseReturner = &returner;` compiles; there are two different instances of `IBaseReturner` in `returner`.  I could imagine the C++ standard going either way (one path is shorter), but I would have expected an error on that line.

Comment: `struct DerivedReturner : public BaseReturner, public virtual DerivedReturner` That doesn't compile, and can't possibly. You have a class deriving from itself. I'm going to assume you meant to derive from `IDerivedReturner`

Comment: @Yakk `IBaseReturner` is a virtual base class; there is, in fact, only one instance of `IBaseReturner` in `DerivedReturner`, making the cast unambiguous.

Comment: @igor it is virtual along only one path.  And this is not the actual code? [MCVE] is needed, not pseudo code.  Voting to close until OP posts a min and accurate example with a link that demonstrates that the code is accurate.  I suspect the actual code might involve different shenanigans, but hard to retype it on my phone, and it turns out I will have to *fix it* as well.

Comment: @Yakk What do you mean, virtual along only one path? There's not a single spot where `IBaseReturner` is inherited non-virtually. [Here's an MCVE](http://rextester.com/VDRJ42083) . Looks like an MSVC bug to me, for what it's worth.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! the 'I' got deleted in editing. Fixed it.

Comment: @Yakk try it out http://rextester.com/KHZXGQ27304

Comment: @igor I mistook BaseReturner for IBaseReturner.

Comment: As a side note: The multiple inheritance is not necessary to reproduce the problem. It's just a leftover from me trying to mimic my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have an undefined behavior (both GCC and Clang compile and execute it fine, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q91vbhjTh), and its run fails due to a bug in MSVC, which is still present in Visual Studio 2019 and 2022.

Reported MSVC bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Invalid-code-generated-for-virtual-inher/1598214

From their response:

> This is related to some issues in the virtual function table layout in the compiler, when virtual inheritance and covariant return types are involved.
> If you are blocked, one possible workaround is to swap the order of the base classes:

```
struct DerivedReturner : public virtual IDerivedReturner, public BaseReturner
```